# Where exactly is my lack of focus?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A few hours ago, out of curiosity, I did post the following question

- [On the legality of seizing narco yachts](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/94824/6854)

which was closed because it "needs to be more focused". If "board and seize" is too **un**focused for Law Stack Exchange, should I post another question focusing specifically on the boarding part and edit the aforementioned question so that it focuses only on the seizing part?  Wouldn't that be disrespectful towards Trish, who has already posted an [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/94826/6854) addressing **both** the boarding and the seizing? ‍☠️

Answer (score 2):

Appending a new question, research, and jurisdictional interaction after receiving an answer can be problematic. In general, this could lead to decreased relevance of posted answers or the need to edit answers to keep up with the changes. You received several flags, and this didn't escape their notice.

As an aside, it's not appropriate to post an answer as a means of reserving a space to subvert a question's closing.

Comment: Where did I append a new question? Since I received criticism, I narrowed the question. In short, I focused more, not less.

Comment: So, showing my work to demonstrate that I value the question is an act of self-sabotage? What kind of incentives are you engineering here?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo please feel free to edit in a way that clarifies. As it stands, the question asks about Portugal boarding/seizing, an autonomous region, piracy, and UNCLOS. Some flags were concerned about too much breadth. Others about the timing of your edits relative to the posted answer.

Comment: Where exactly is too much breadth?  The question is extremely focused.  The Portuguese Navy boarded a yacht in the Atlantic, probably outside Portugal's territorial waters. Since I assume that Portugal is interested in preserving the myth of rule of law, thereby avoiding acquiring the reputation of a pirate republic, the Portuguese Navy must have acted within some legal framework, say, article XYZ in some legal document. My question pertains to the articles invoked when boarding the yacht and that render this quasi-piratical operation lawful.